# Looking at exporting multiple shapefiles with corresponding input names

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcMap 10.6 and ModelBuilder.

I have input points (LinepointS1) from a geometric network which contain sub 3000 points that I would like to trace downstream from and have the model spit out a shapefile which shows the start point/flag and downstream route and name the shapefile by an attribute from the linepoints1 i.e. an identifiable id.

I have managed to run the model so it'll create 1 shapefile with one point and downstream line and name it test.shp. The issue is that as it iterates for each of the 3000 points, the final output overwrites the previous point output.

[image]

How can I output different names with each pass?

Comment: You can likely just name your final output %Value%.shp.

Comment: @lambertj - thanks for this. this has now enabled the model to output the multiple shapefiles. wondering if there was a way to tell it to use a certain field in the LINEPOINTS1 table as it's name?